# Room Error while getting data from table - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method createCancellationSignal()

Tags: android, android-room

I am trying to get data from the table using the room database. I am getting below crash while getting data from the database (Insert works fine).

Note - I am using room database in my dynamic module.

Any solution for this?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method createCancellationSignal()Landroid/os/CancellationSignal; in class Landroidx/room/util/DBUtil; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.room.util.DBUtil' appears in /data/app/~~F1m2f48w3u2dp2H_OlOBQA==/com.abc.yt-eZz63VSW7DNVYrhzadBv4g==/base.apk)
        at com.abc.yt.database.RankSearchHistoryDAO_Impl.getSearchHistory1(RankSearchHistoryDAO_Impl.java:239)
        at com.abc.yt.uiHandler.RankCheckerUIHandler$saveResultsInDb$1.invokeSuspend(RankCheckerUIHandler.kt:64)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

---

### Code to get and save data in database

```
private fun saveResultsInDb(rank: Int) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val searchHistory = RankSearchHistory(
                videoId = fragment.getViewModel().mVideoId,
                keyword = fragment.getViewModel().searchQuery.keyword,
                rank = rank,
                countryCode = fragment.getViewModel().regionCode,
                createDate = currentTime,
                updateDate = currentTime
            )
            val searchHistoryDAO = fragment.getDatabase().getRankSearchHistoryDao()
           
            val dbSearchHistoryData: List<RankSearchHistory>? = searchHistoryDAO.getSearchHistory()
            if (dbSearchHistoryData.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                searchHistoryDAO.insertSearchHistory(searchHistory)
            } else {
                searchHistoryDAO.updateSearchHistory(searchHistory.videoId, searchHistory.keyword, searchHistory.countryCode, searchHistory.rank, currentTime)
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM RankSearchHistory")
suspend fun getSearchHistory1(): List<RankSearchHistory>?
```

Comment: Ankush have you found any solution for this?

Comment: @VishalJha it worked after downgrading the room version to 2.1.0